# Conditional SQL date parameters to skip weekend days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, conditional-statements

New to SQL and am totally lost on this. Trying write a query to pull new accounts opened the prior day, which is can do easily for Tuesday-Friday. But on Mondays it is pulling Sunday and everything I've attempted has errored out.

This is the closest I've come, but its still wrong on the last line. I think I'm trying to apply excel vba type logic and its just not liking me. Can someone please give it a look over?

Thanks!

```
SELECT
    PortfolioCode as "Account", 
    f.reportheading1 as "Name", 
    d.portfoliostatus as "Status", 
    e.investmentstrategy as "Strategy",
    e.brokersource as "Broker", 
    e.referringfirm as "RefBy", 
    e.custodian as "Bank",
    e.manager as "Manager", 
    e.administrator as "APM", 
    d.initialvalue as "Open Value", 
    b.StartDate as "Start Date", 
    e.percentcash as "Cash%", 
    e.targetmvequity as "Eqt Trgt", 
    e.targetmvfixed as "FI Trgt", 
    e.munistrategy as "Muni Strat", 
    e.nationalmuni as "Nat. Muni", 
    e.statemunistrategy as "State Strat.", 
    e.residency as "Residency"
FROM
    AdvPortfolioBaseExt as A
INNER JOIN
    AdvPortfoliobase AS B ON A.PortfolioBaseID = b.PortfolioBaseID
INNER JOIN
    advportfolio AS C ON A.PortfolioBaseID = c.PortfolioID
INNER JOIN
    advapp.vportfolio AS D ON A.PortfolioBaseID = D.PortfolioID
INNER JOIN
    advportfoliobaseext AS E ON A.portfoliobaseid = e.portfoliobaseID
INNER JOIN
    advapp.vportfoliobase AS F ON a.PortfolioBaseID = f.PortfolioBaseID
WHERE 
    c.portfoliostatus <> 'Closed'
    AND IIF(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 2, b.startdate > GETDATE() - 3, b.startdate > GETDATE()-1)
```

Comment: As a general performance issue, without looking at the details of your question, you should call GetDate() once, and store its value, otherwise it will be called every time it is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEPART(dw)` depends on the value of the server setting `DATEFIRST`.  So, I avoid it...

```
WHERE
    b.startdate
    >=
    getdate() - CASE DATENAME(dw, getdate()) WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 2
                                             WHEN 'Monday' THEN 3
                                                           ELSE 1 END
```

Also, your errors are because the return values from `IIF()` can't be the results of logical comparisons.  It has to return a scalar fvalue of a type that exists in SQL Server *(which doesn't have a boolean type)*

This is the valid...

```
WHERE s.startdate >= IIF(x = y, a, b)
```

This is not valid...

```
WHERE IIF(x = y, s.startdate >= a, s.startdate >= b)
```

So, what you wrote could be...

```
WHERE
  s.startDate > IIF(datepart(dw,getdate()) = 2, getdate()-3, getdate()-1)
```

Though, that's wrong if executed on Sunday...

Comment: You prefer to avoid `DatePart( dw )` since it depends on the setting of `DateFirst`, but then choose an alternative that depends on the setting of `Language`. `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill but you may want to parameterize the query then pass the date value.  Otherwise I would just do a simple CTE and set a datetime variable which would be used for the where condition.  SQL below is for 2005 (Newer versions have different functions).  I wasn't sure which version you were using so I picked the lowest common denominator.  Anyway this should work and if there are indexed fields they won't be affected by a computed condition in the WHERE clause that you are attempting.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME;

;WITH WeekDayOffset AS (
    SELECT 1 as WkDay, -2 as OffSet 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 as WkDay, 0 as OffSet 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3 as WkDay, 0 as OffSet 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4 as WkDay, 0 as OffSet 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5 as WkDay, 0 as OffSet 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6 as WkDay, 0 as OffSet 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7 as WkDay, -1 as Offset
)

SELECT  @Date = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, Offset, GETDATE()),101) AS datetime)
FROM WeekDayOffset
WHERE WkDay = DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())


SELECT
    PortfolioCode as "Account", 
    f.reportheading1 as "Name", 
    d.portfoliostatus as "Status", 
    e.investmentstrategy as "Strategy",
    e.brokersource as "Broker", 
    e.referringfirm as "RefBy", 
    e.custodian as "Bank",
    e.manager as "Manager", 
    e.administrator as "APM", 
    d.initialvalue as "Open Value", 
    b.StartDate as "Start Date", 
    e.percentcash as "Cash%", 
    e.targetmvequity as "Eqt Trgt", 
    e.targetmvfixed as "FI Trgt", 
    e.munistrategy as "Muni Strat", 
    e.nationalmuni as "Nat. Muni", 
    e.statemunistrategy as "State Strat.", 
    e.residency as "Residency"
FROM
    AdvPortfolioBaseExt as A
INNER JOIN
    AdvPortfoliobase AS B ON A.PortfolioBaseID = b.PortfolioBaseID
INNER JOIN
    advportfolio AS C ON A.PortfolioBaseID = c.PortfolioID
INNER JOIN
    advapp.vportfolio AS D ON A.PortfolioBaseID = D.PortfolioID
INNER JOIN
    advportfoliobaseext AS E ON A.portfoliobaseid = e.portfoliobaseID
INNER JOIN
    advapp.vportfoliobase AS F ON a.PortfolioBaseID = f.PortfolioBaseID
WHERE 
    c.portfoliostatus <> 'Closed'
    AND b.startdate > @Date
```